# For Facebook SDK / Unity / Android Login setting on Facebook site:

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

What setting should the Login enable / disable be set to for a android game for unity in the settings on the facebook dev app settings????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it to enabled if you want to use Facebook login in your app.

Comment: I thought so.  Thanks for clearing that up....if you notice when aaron is explaining the "friendsmash" game he doesn't even say anything about it....kind of lame if you ask me.

Comment: @benp Can you offer me some help regarding the facebook sdk. Here's the link bit.ly/1bKnOPo